# Site Logo URI adjustment

Tags: site, inheritance, site-logo

I uploaded my company's site logo successfully to my site and whenever I created sites under my site collection, the logo is inheriting successfully. But the problem is when I click the site logo from any sub-site, it's taking me to that particular site's homepage, but not to the top-level site. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The OOTB master page uses the ~site token as the URL to surround the site logo, just change this to ~sitecollection/ (the trailing slash is necessary) or even / depending on your particular requirements.

In v4.master the section to change is at line 297 and should wind up looking something like:

```
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic" >
    <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/siteIcon.png" runat="server"/>
</SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

out of the box, as said it is not possible. However, doing it for all sites separate would be ....... ().

Better to use a little script (JScript) finding the link in the DOM (by name or ID) and replacing it with the required URL.

Comment: Using javascript for this is not the best approach. SharePoint has a built-in url token system that should be leveraged

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the logo URL from SharePoint Designer... No options are available Out of the box...